# How to declare react navigation argument with typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to use `typescript` with my `react hook` component.

I use `react-navigation` for my router.

Create project with `npx react-native init MyTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript@6.2.0`

version is

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
```

Here is what I try

RootScreen.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

interface IRootScreen {
  navigation: () => void;
}

const RootScreen: React.FC<IRootScreen> = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MainStack')}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>I am RootScreen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

export default RootScreen;
```

I can navigate to `MainStack` successfully.

But `navigation.navigate('MainStack')` will shows `type () => void no argument navigate` on my editor Visual Studio Code.

Is any thing wrong with my interface or I still have to do something with the code ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
import {
  NavigationParams,
  NavigationScreenProp,
  NavigationState,
} from 'react-navigation';

interface IRootScreen {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But navigation.navigate('MainStack') will shows type () => void no argument navigate on

Because that's how you have defined the `navigation` prop's type:

> ```js
> interface IRootScreen {
>  navigation: () => void;
> }
> ```

You need to use `NavigationStackProp`:

```js
import { NavigationStackProp } from 'react-navigation-stack';

interface IRootScreen {
  navigation: NavigationStackProp;
};
```

Read the official docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/typescript.html